# QSvgGenerator isn't writing to its outputDevice

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to get the output of `QSvgGenerator` into a string for use in-line in HTML. I can use the `.setFileName(...)` method and get output as a file, but `.setOutputDevice(&qbuffer)` doesn't add anything to the qbuffer (and I can use `qbuffer.write(...);` to write strings into the buffer before and after the `scene.render(&painter);` rendering operation gets called on the `QSvgGenerator`, and see that those strings are making it into the buffer).

The following code snippet will happily write to a file, but won't give me an SVG string, the only difference in code paths is that one uses `.setFileName(...)` and the other uses `.setOutputDevice(...)`.

```
QGraphicsScene scene;
QPen backgroundPen(Qt::black);
QRectF backgroundRect(-10,-10,20,20);
QBrush backgroundBrush(QColor(128,64,64));
scene.addRect(backgroundRect, backgroundPen, backgroundBrush);

QBuffer qbuffer;
qbuffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);

QSvgGenerator svgGenerator;

if (argc >= 2)
{
    svgGenerator.setFileName(argv[1]);
}
else
{
    svgGenerator.setOutputDevice(&qbuffer);
}
svgGenerator.setSize(QSize(128,128));
svgGenerator.setTitle("Title");
svgGenerator.setDescription("Description");

QPainter painter( &svgGenerator );
scene.render( &painter );

qbuffer.seek(0);
QString s(qbuffer.readAll());
qInfo() << s;
```

Qt 5.9, Ubuntu 17.10, if that matters.

Comment: Perfect: calling end() or making sure the QPainter gets destroyed works. Thank you! Marked it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#end):

> **bool QPainter::end()**
>
> Ends painting. Any resources used while painting are released. You
>   don't normally need to call this since it is called by the destructor.
>
> Returns true if the painter is no longer active; otherwise returns
>   false.

In your case you must finish the painting:

```
[...]
QPainter painter( &svgGenerator );
scene.render( &painter );
painter.end();

qbuffer.seek(0);
QString s(qbuffer.readAll());
qInfo() << s;
```

Output:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n<svg width=\"45.1556mm\" height=\"45.1556mm\"\n xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\"  version=\"1.2\" baseProfile=\"tiny\">\n<title>Title</title>\n<desc>Description</desc>\n<defs>\n</defs>\n<g fill=\"none\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"1\" fill-rule=\"evenodd\" stroke-linecap=\"square\" stroke-linejoin=\"bevel\" >\n\n<g fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-opacity=\"1\" stroke-width=\"1\" stroke-linecap=\"square\" stroke-linejoin=\"bevel\" transform=\"matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)\"\nfont-family=\"Cantarell\" font-size=\"11\" font-weight=\"400\" font-style=\"normal\" \n>\n</g>\n\n<g fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-opacity=\"1\" stroke-width=\"1\" stroke-linecap=\"square\" stroke-linejoin=\"bevel\" transform=\"matrix(6.09524,0,0,6.09524,64,64)\"\nfont-family=\"Cantarell\" font-size=\"11\" font-weight=\"400\" font-style=\"normal\" \n>\n</g>\n\n<g fill=\"#804040\" fill-opacity=\"1\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-opacity=\"1\" stroke-width=\"1\" stroke-linecap=\"square\" stroke-linejoin=\"bevel\" transform=\"matrix(6.09524,0,0,6.09524,64,64)\"\nfont-family=\"Cantarell\" font-size=\"11\" font-weight=\"400\" font-style=\"normal\" \n>\n<rect x=\"-10\" y=\"-10\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\"/>\n</g>\n\n<g fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-opacity=\"1\" stroke-width=\"1\" stroke-linecap=\"square\" stroke-linejoin=\"bevel\" transform=\"matrix(6.09524,0,0,6.09524,64,64)\"\nfont-family=\"Cantarell\" font-size=\"11\" font-weight=\"400\" font-style=\"normal\" \n>\n</g>\n\n<g fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#000000\" stroke-opacity=\"1\" stroke-width=\"1\" stroke-linecap=\"square\" stroke-linejoin=\"bevel\" transform=\"matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)\"\nfont-family=\"Cantarell\" font-size=\"11\" font-weight=\"400\" font-style=\"normal\" \n>\n</g>\n</g>\n</svg>\n"
```